# Filling ExpendableListView with database entries

Tags: android, database, android-listview, expandablelistview

I'm using some sample to **ExpendableList**, I'm stuck at the very end of the project.

I won't be pasting the whole code because nobody would read that. There are parts that could be something wrong with.

There is something wrong with **adapter** I think. When I set it for a ListViev I get a blan page. There is no exception, everything seems to be working. Activity starts but **list is empty.**

**Fragment of my activity class**

```
adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, new ArrayList<String>(),
                new ArrayList<ArrayList<Expense>>());        

        //database cursor
        Cursor cursor = db.SQLDb.rawQuery("SELECT "+db.EXPENSE_CATEGORY+","+db.EXPENSE_DATE+
                ", SUM("+db.EXPENSE_VALUE+") 'SUM' , STRFTIME('%m', "+db.EXPENSE_DATE+") \"MONTH\", STRFTIME('%Y', "+db.EXPENSE_DATE+
                ") \"YEAR\" FROM "+db.TABLE_EXPENSES+ " GROUP BY "+db.EXPENSE_CATEGORY+ ", MONTH, YEAR ORDER BY MONTH DESC, YEAR DESC"   , null);

  //geting values from table            
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{

                String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.EXPENSE_CATEGORY));             
                double sum = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("SUM")); 
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.EXPENSE_DATE));
                String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MONTH")) + " " +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("YEAR")); ;       

//adding new object to adapter
                adapter.addExpense(new Expense(category, sum, date, month));


            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }       

//seting the adapter for ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Fragment of ExpendalbeListAdapter class**

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> groups;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Expense>> children;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> groups, ArrayList<ArrayList<Expense>> children) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
    this.children = children;
}

public void addExpense(Expense expense) {
    if (!groups.contains(expense.getMonth())) {
        groups.add(expense.getMonth());
    }
    int index = groups.indexOf(expense.getMonth());
    if (children.size() < index + 1) {
        children.add(new ArrayList<Expense>());
    }
    children.get(index).add(expense);
}

// Return a child view. You can load your custom layout here.
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Expense expense = (Expense) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_child, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
    tv.setText("   " + expense.getCategory());          

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String group = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_group, null);  
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
    tv.setText(group);
    return convertView;
}
```

**Expense class**

```
 public class Expense {
        private String category;
        private double value;
        private String date;
        private String month;   

        public Expense(String category, double value, String date, String month){
            this.category = category;
            this.value = value;
            this.date = date;
            this.month = month;
        }
    }
```

**Layouts**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="none"></ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dip"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_width="40dip" android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvGroup" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dip" android:text="Groups" android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="17dip"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dip"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_width="40dip" android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dip" android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="5dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="17dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/tvChild"
                android:text="Children" android:textColor="#ffCCCC22"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OMG...WTF?!?! Man...your approach sucks. SQL queries,data parse..in UI THREAD?!?! So..try to do this.
1. Create an Activity that holds the expandable list, and the ExpandableListAdapter.
2. Create Array or some other structure to hold the list items.
3. Create thread that reads and parse the data from database.
4. Create interface and implement it in the activity.
5. Show progress dialog. When the thread finishes with data loading and parsing, pass on the data structure (array, hash and so on) to the activity's interface method. 
6. Create adapter and fill the list view.

Comment: Thanks for fedback. I'm a rookie, but I assume, this way of loading data is way too slow for creating a list right? Still it doesn't explains why I get a blank activity. All I got is 5 entries in this database, so it can't be a matter of speed. Sure, in the future I'll need to rebuild this. This is the way I learn things

Comment: Run in debug mode. Put breakpoint inside of the adapter and check what  is wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I was missing some methods in ExpendableListAdapter class, but generally it works now. However, as Pepi says it's not most efficient way of doing it, so use at own risk.

Here is example I followed
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html